# System Verilog DPI Checker masking 128-bit value

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, monitor, bitvector, system-verilog-dpi

I am writing a DPI checker(.cpp file), In this, Checker reads the 128-bit value on every line and I want to mask it with a 128-bit mask and compare it with RTL value but the issue I am seeing is the data type from which I am creating the mask only holds 32-bit value and I need to do bitwise anding with original data. Can anyone provide any suggestions?

```
typedef struct {
   BitVector<128>   data
} read_line;

svBitVecVal  mask;
mask = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;

BitVector<128>   data_masked;
data_masked = read_line->data & mask;
```

Here `svBitVecVal` can only hold a maximum of 32bit value. `data_masked` will not show the correct value if the mask is more than 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got your `BitVector` template from, but `svBitVecVal` is usually used as `svBitVecVal*` pointing to an array of 32 bits *chunks*.

`mask` needs to be a 4 element array to hold 128 bits.

And you'll need to either convert `mask` to a `BitVector` type first, or make sure it has the right overloaded function to do it for you.